# How do you stop a script from running if the API doesn't return anything?

Tags: python, api

How do you stop a script from running if when you call an API the results are an empty array? 
With the script I want to write the response if there is one to a csv which I have working fine, but if there is no data it errors out and I would like to just ignore the response and terminate.

This is the json response that I get.When there are no results
`{
    "people": [],
    "totalpeoplecount": 0,
    "status": "Success",
    "messages": []
}`

Here is the code I'm using

```
`def get_people():
  url = testapi.com
  headers = {'Authorization': 'Token '+bd_login()}
  r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  bdResponse = r.json()
  people= bdResponse['people']
  if bdResponse.get('people',[]):
      exit(1)
  return people`
```

Comment: It's hard to suggest anyting specific without seeing your code but the obvious answer (now appeared in an actual answer) is just to check the response and use an if block to skip the subsequent steps if it is empty.

Comment: `if not results: sys.exit()`

Answer (score 1):

If you get this:

```
res = {
    "people": [],
    "totalpeoplecount": 0,
    "status": "Success",
    "messages": []
}
```

You could:

```
if not res.get('people', []):
    # Print something if you need
    exit(1)
```

Comment: When I attempt to use this, I get this exception 

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'list' object has no attribute 'get

Comment: @user0015 Please update you question with code you are using.

Comment: @user0015 bdResponse should be a dict, not a list. Can you please print it?

Comment: {'people': [], 'totalpeoplecount': 0, 'status': 'Success', 'messages': []}

Comment: @user0015 `AttributeError` does not make sense. But, from you actual code, you could replace `if` statement with: `if not people: ...`